# GroupBy based on conditions in Spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframe,

Dataframe1 contains key/value pairs:

```
+------+-----------------+    
| Key  | Value           |
+------+-----------------+
| key1 | Column1         |
+------+-----------------+
| key2 | Column2         |
+------+-----------------+
| key3 | Column1,Column3 |
+------+-----------------+
```

Second dataframe:

This is actual dataframe where I need to apply groupBy operation

```
+---------+---------+---------+--------+
| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Amount |
+---------+---------+---------+--------+
| A       | A1      | XYZ     | 100    |
+---------+---------+---------+--------+
| A       | A1      | XYZ     | 100    |
+---------+---------+---------+--------+
| A       | A2      | XYZ     | 10     |
+---------+---------+---------+--------+
| A       | A3      | PQR     | 100    |
+---------+---------+---------+--------+
| B       | B1      | XYZ     | 200    |
+---------+---------+---------+--------+
| B       | B2      | PQR     | 280    |
+---------+---------+---------+--------+
| B       | B3      | XYZ     | 20     |
+---------+---------+---------+--------+
```

Dataframe1 contains the key,value columns
It has to take the keys from dataframe1, it has to take the respective value and do the groupBy operation on the dataframe2

```
Dframe= df.groupBy($"key").sum("amount").show()
```

**Expected Output:** Generate three dataframes based on number of keys in dataframe

```
d1= df.grouBy($"key1").sum("amount").show()
```

it has to be : `df.grouBy($"column1").sum("amount").show()`

```
+---+-----+
| A | 310 |
+---+-----+
| B | 500 |
+---+-----+
```

Code:

```
d2=df.groupBy($"key2").sum("amount").show()

result: df.grouBy($"column2").sum("amount").show()
```

dataframe:

```
+----+-----+
| A1 | 200 |
+----+-----+
| A2 | 10  |
+----+-----+
```

Code :

```
d3.df.groupBy($"key3").sum("amount").show()
```

DataFrame:

```
+---+-----+-----+
| A | XYZ | 320 |
+---+-----+-----+
| A | PQR | 10  |
+---+-----+-----+
| B | XYZ | 220 |
+---+-----+-----+
| B | PQR | 280 |
+---+-----+-----+
```

In future, if I add more keys , it has to show the dataframe. Can someone help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the key value dataframe as ( which I suggest you not to form dataframe from the source data, reason is given below)

```
+----+---------------+
|Key |Value          |
+----+---------------+
|key1|Column1        |
|key2|Column2        |
|key3|Column1,Column3|
+----+---------------+
```

and actual dataframe as

```
+-------+-------+-------+------+
|Column1|Column2|Column3|Amount|
+-------+-------+-------+------+
|A      |A1     |XYZ    |100   |
|A      |A1     |XYZ    |100   |
|A      |A2     |XYZ    |10    |
|A      |A3     |PQR    |100   |
|B      |B1     |XYZ    |200   |
|B      |B2     |PQR    |280   |
|B      |B3     |XYZ    |20    |
+-------+-------+-------+------+
```

I would suggest you not to convert the first dataframe to rdd maps as

```
val maps = df1.rdd.map(row => row(0) -> row(1)).collect()
```

And then loop the maps as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
for(kv <- maps){
  df2.groupBy(kv._2.toString.split(",").map(col): _*).agg(sum($"Amount")).show(false)
  //you can store the results in separate dataframes or write them to files or database
}
```

You should have follwing outputs

```
+-------+-----------+
|Column1|sum(Amount)|
+-------+-----------+
|B      |500        |
|A      |310        |
+-------+-----------+

+-------+-----------+
|Column2|sum(Amount)|
+-------+-----------+
|A2     |10         |
|B2     |280        |
|B1     |200        |
|B3     |20         |
|A3     |100        |
|A1     |200        |
+-------+-----------+

+-------+-------+-----------+
|Column1|Column3|sum(Amount)|
+-------+-------+-----------+
|B      |PQR    |280        |
|B      |XYZ    |220        |
|A      |PQR    |100        |
|A      |XYZ    |210        |
+-------+-------+-----------+
```